# alembic db migration concurrently

Tags: python, flask, concurrency, alembic

I have multiple flask apps connected to the same database backend for high availability purposes. There is a problem when app instances try to migrate database concurrently using alembic! What's the best way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alembic [does not](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sqlalchemy-alembic/I2AAEUdF2dQ/mM2dokcZCAAJ) support simultaneous migration. Your best bet is to do it manually.